# Does the DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute.Order property not work with ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, annotations, metadata, asp.net-mvc-futures

I set values for the [Order property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.order(v=VS.100).aspx) of the [Display attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411771(v=VS.100).aspx) in my model metadata.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(OccasionMetadata))]
public partial class Occasion
{
    private class OccasionMetadata
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public object Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Title", Order = 0)]
        public object Designation { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Display(Order = 3)]
        public object Summary { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Order = 1)]
        public object Start { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Order = 2)]
        public object Finish { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I present my models in strongly-typed views using the [DisplayForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayformodel.aspx) and [EditorForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorformodel(v=VS.100).aspx) methods.

```
<%= Html.DisplayForModel() %>
```

and

```
<%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
```

But, ASP.NET MVC 2 displays the fields out of order! What might I have wrong?

Comment: I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 RC.

Comment: "Please note that the ASP.NET 4 Futures assembly requires .NET 4 RTM, and will not work with any builds of .NET 4 or VS 2010 prior to RTM."

Comment: I've installed Visual Studio 2010 RTM and have tried to add the ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures to my project. The Display attribute still isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> .NET 4 DataAnnotations comes with a
>   new [Display attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx) that has
>   several properties including
>   specifying the value that is used for
>   display in the UI and a ResourceType.
>   Unfortunately, this attribute is new
>   and is **not supported in MVC 2 RTM**.
>
> The good news is it will be supported
>   and is **currently available in the MVC
>   Futures** release.
>
> The steps to get this working are
>   shown below...

from [Localization in ASP.NET MVC 2 using ModelMetadata](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/27/localization-in-asp-net-mvc-2-using-modelmetadata.aspx) by Raj Kaimal

Comment: Thanks for writing this, Raj. It's a big help.

Comment: I've installed Visual Studio 2010 RTM and have tried to add the ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures to my project. The Display attribute still isn't working.

Comment: Zach, did you follow all the steps in my post?

Comment: @Zack Peterson In MVC2 you will have to use the attribute System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute instead DisplayAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

Brad Wilson said November 2009:

> There is no support for order in MVC
>   2, and it's not likely to be there
>   until MVC 3. One major reason is that
>   DataAnnotations in .NET 4 have added
>   ordering support, but since we rely on
>   3.5, we cannot do it yet.

from [comment](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-5-master-page-templates.html#comment-6a00e54fbd8c4988340120a6704a7a970b) on "ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 5: Master Page Templates"

Comment: Using the model metadata provider in ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures allows Name to work, but not Order.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998865

Comment: Confirmed June 9, 2010  
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html#comment-6a00e54fbd8c4988340133f05a28b5970b