# How do I install ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, annotations, metadata, asp.net-mvc-futures

I want to use the [DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute.Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.order%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property to arrange my fields when using the [DisplayForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayformodel.aspx) and [EditorForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorformodel%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) methods.

> Related question:
>   [Does the
>   DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute.Order
>   property not work with ASP.NET MVC
>   2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837952/does-the-dataannotations-displayattribute-order-property-not-work-with-asp-net-mv)

I think that I need to use the [ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742). But I can't get it to work.

How do I install ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures?

Why are my fields still out of order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download [ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742) from CodePlex.
2. Save its files somewhere in the file system:

   > C:\Program Files\Microsoft
   >   ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures\
3. In the project, right-click **References** and choose **Add Reference**
4. Browse to and then select file **Microsoft.Web.Mvc.AspNet4.dll**
5. Register the model metadata provider in **Global.asax.cs**:

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       ...
       ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DataAnnotations4ModelMetadataProvider();
       DataAnnotations4ModelValidatorProvider.RegisterProvider();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You should just need to download the futures DLL (Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll), add a reference to it in Visual Studio, and reference the namespace `Microsoft.Web.Mvc`

Data Annotations are just attributes, so you may not see compiler errors if there is a problem.  The attribute will just not work.  You should obtain the source for futures and include it in your project, so that you can breakpoint the appropriate attribute servicing code and make sure it is firing.

Comment: I think Robert meant the Microsoft.Web.MVC.dll as that's the futures assembly

Comment: @Zack: Sorry about that.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to register the metadata provider in your global.asax.

```
DataAnnotations4ModelMetadataProvider.RegisterProvider();
```

And also, Microsoft.Web.Mvc.AspNet4.dll is the assembly. You can get it from here http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742