# how to display form items in a specific order which is retrieved from a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, sorting

My customer wants a form which has to contain the following items:

- name
- email
- address
- state

On the admin panel of this application he wants to set the order of the form items on the admin panel.
What is the best way to approach this? i want to keep correct validation for each field.

I was thinking of an array that contains the order of the form items but i have no idea how to display the form items in that order.

The sort order needs tobe set in the database.

I would appreciate help

Comment: Do you mean each of them has to be a textbox or just objects which you will store in array and then sort

Comment: yes each of the form items are text boxes. i just want to be able to change the order on a live application. and i need a correct approach to achieve that

Comment: He is talking about winforms

Comment: @georgi-it, not at all.

Comment: it's not winforms. The sort order needs tobe set in a database... i need to know a to display the form items in an order which is set in the database.

Comment: Check this answer to a similar question: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2838083/674700](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2838083/674700).

Comment: @Alex The display order is dynamic i can't set the display order in the model directly as a static value. do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create a database table, `TextBoxes` to hold the settings (which will also be modified from the administration panel), with the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE TextBoxes
(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Ordinal int NOT NULL,
    TextBoxName nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Add a few records to it by using `TextBoxName` values like `name`, `address`, `state` etc - this will later be used to map the UI control - and the desired order in the `Ordinal` column. Add the table to your model.

Create the following class (I'll assume that the entity containing the properties in the question is named `Contact`):

```
public class MyDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider : 
    System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata 
        CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, 
            Type containerType, 
            Func<object> modelAccessor, 
            Type modelType, 
            string propertyName)
    {
        if (containerType == typeof(Contact))
        {
            // get the repository instance  
            var db = new MyModelEntities();
            // find the current textbox by it's property name
            var textBox = db.TextBoxes
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.TextBoxName == propertyName);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName) && textBox != null)
                attributes = attributes.Union(new List<Attribute>() {
                    new DisplayAttribute() { Order = textBox.Ordinal } 
                });
        }
        return base.CreateMetadata(attributes, 
            containerType, 
            modelAccessor, 
            modelType, 
            propertyName);
    }
}
```

In the *Global.asax.cs* file, modify the `Application_Start` method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // set the current metadata provider to our custom class
    ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MyDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();
    // other method content
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    // etc
}
```

**Note:** 
The example above will allow you to dynamically change the order of the text boxes for one model, but if you add another property in the `TextBoxes` model to hold the order for the properties for multiple models, you could extend the logic to your other models through some extra filtering.

Comment: Thanks going to test this soon and going to mark it as answered if it works

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to order them on the client-side.

**Steps to accomplish this:**

- In some way, you would have to associate each form field with the respective order number.
- Form the HTML in a way that you could identify the order of each field.
- Implement javascript logic to handle the HTML and display the fields in the proper order.

**An example:**

Let's say that each form field would be on a div with a common identifier and the order number:

```
<div id="official_div">
</div>
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="form_field_2">
       <--! Name Field here -->
    </div>
    <div id="form_field_1">
       <--! Email Field here -->
    </div>
    <div id="form_field_3">
      <--! Address Field here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, knowing the number of fields, you could implement some javascript logic to get those fields together with the proper order and put them on the actual form field official div:

```
  var officialDiv = document.getElementById('official_div');
  for(var i =1; i <= numberOfFields; i++)
  {
       var element  = document.getElementById('form_field_' + i);
       //include element inside officialDiv 
  }
```